# guide to create debian package in netbeans

Tags: ubuntu, debian, c++, installation-package, netbeans-7.3

I've written a C++ application aided by netbeans on ubuntu. In netbeans there is a build feature to build debian package. When I build the package using it I am not getting desired result. The files I am installing to linux filesystem using makefile are not being put into debian package.

in my makefile

```
install:
    install config.xml /etc/${APPNAME}.conf.xml
    install devices.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/${APPNAME}.rules
    install error.log /var/log/${APPNAME}.log
    install init.conf /etc/init/${APPNAME}.conf
    install init.d /etc/init.d/${APPNAME}
    chmod u+x ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
    ./${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}} -i
```

but after building the package with netbeans, in the build .deb archive there is only usr/bin/${APPNAME} file. How to build debian package as expected.